# nodejs spawn not constructing valid vim command

Tags: node.js

If I have this script in node, saved as `example.js`:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

childProcess.spawn('vim', ['-u NONE', 'test.txt'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

I would expect that `node example.js` would be (roughly) equivalent to calling:

```
vim -u NONE test.txt
```

However, when I execute the script I get:

```
$ node example.js
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 26 2020 07:37:17)
Garbage after option argument: "-u NONE"
More info with: "vim -h"
```

Running `vim -u NONE example.txt` directly works just fine.

Am I misunderstanding / misusing `spawn` somehow?

**Edit**:

This, without the `-u NONE` flag, works just fine:

```
childProcess.spawn('vim', ['test.txt'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

It's adding `-u NONE` that for some reason vim doesn't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
const cp = spawn('vim', ['test.txt'], {stdio: ['inherit']})
cp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Spawn open a child_process which is attached to the const cp(in this ex), this method stream its output (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/child_process.html), so we need to consume it. We pipe the cp.stdout to the parent_process process.stdout. That open a new tty within: the child_process.stdout

We can make it more straightforward by setting the stdio childProcess.output option to 'inherit' and(optional) forwarding the childProcess.stderr to its own childProcess.stdout (which is already inherit by the motherProcess, so will be output automatically).

This should output the same as previously

```
 const cp = spawn(
             'vim', ['test.txt'], 
             {stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', process.stdout]}
           )
```

To run precisely the command `vim -u NONE file.ext`. The first argument is the executable path and the second is an array containing the flags to pass to the command. Inside this array each single element(separate with space) of the flags must be an element of the array. So in this case that should work

```
const cp = spawn(
             'vim', ['-u', 'NONE', 'test.txt'], 
             {stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', process.stdout]}
           )
```

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question a bit. Indeed you're right, dropping `-u NONE` works. But I don't understand why `-u NONE` confuses vim in that way. `spawn` should be calling it directly as `vim -u NONE test.text`, from my understanding.

Comment: Oooh, ok. The syntaxe of the flags inside the array is incorrect, see the edit of my post.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like this:

```
const { exec } = require("child-process");

exec('vim -u NONE example.txt', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```